# Set variables to output based on regex on swig

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a C++ library that I want to use in Python with SWIG. Many functions in that library have output arguments, arguments I have to set manually as OUTPUT.

The thing is these arguments are prefixed with "ao_" (argument output).

Is there a way to set every arguments prefixed with "ao_" to OUTPUT ?